# How to loop through folder and enter file names into function

Tags: bash

I'm trying to loop through a folder and execute a command based on the ending of the file name.

I have tried some variations on

```
for f in *.fastq.gz; do [[ "$f" =~ ^([^_]+_[^_]+)_.*(_[^_]+)_[0-9]+\.fastq\.gz$ ]]; 
function ( firstfile_R1 secondfile_R2); 
done
```

but I can't figure out how to do this for two inputs.

My filename convention is

> filename_S[1-24]_R1_merged.fastq.gz

or

> filename_S[1-24]_R2_merged.fastq.gz

All of my files are paired with R1 and R2 equivalents and I am hoping there is an automated way to run this in the terminal.

I'm using this on the trimmomatic function but I think it should be the same for anyone needing two inputs to a function.

I'm hoping to use a loop to enter in each pair of samples to a command function but I can't figure out how to loop correctly so that I get the correct _R1 and _R2 files so that I can enter them in my function.

Comment: What about a nested for-loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I assume what you posted was pseudocode, but start by trying that in https://www.shellcheck.net/

Then try something like this -

```
for f in [^_]*_S[0-9]*_R1_[^_]*.fastq.gz
do myfunc "$f" "${f/_R1_/_R2_}" # parallel filenames assumed
done
```

Or better, imho -

```
for f in *_S[0-9]*_R1_*.fastq.gz # less specificity, but less noisy
do myfunc "$f" "${f/_R1_/_R2_}"
done
```

Comment: I think I over simplified earlier but thank you so much for the solution! Here is what I ended up doing because in some parts of the input I needed just parts of the filename  `for f in [^_]*_S[0-9]*_R1_[^_]*.fastq.gz;
do java -jar /trimmomatic-0.39.jar PE -phred33 "$f" "${f/_R1_/_R2_}" "${f/.fastq.gz/}"_paired.fq.gz  "${f/.fastq.gz/}"_unpaired.fq.gz "${f/_R1_merged.fastq.gz/_R2_merged}"_paired.fq.gz "${f/_R1_merged.fastq.gz/_R2_merged}"_unpaired.fq.gz ILLUMINACLIP:TruSeq3-PE.fa:2:30:10 LEADING:3 TRAILING:3 SLIDINGWINDOW:4:15 MINLEN:36;done`

Comment: Glad to help. :)